# create a video from a batch of 400 images with diffrent time for each image

Tags: video, images, timelapse

I want to create a video or slideshow from a batch of 400 images (.jpg) with different time lapse (I have a text file which shows how much time for each image in millisecond)

For example:

```
image 0001.jpg is 225 msec
image 0002.jpg is 480 msec
image 0003.jpg is 1200 msec
```

How can I create such a video with minimal effort?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a video from each image, and then combine them all. With `mencoder` you could do the following:

This will [create a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468274/ffmpeg-images-to-video-script-anyone) with 1 frame per second from `image.jpg`:

```
mencoder "mf://image.jpg" -ovc x264 -mf  fps=1  -o output.avi
```

This will take two videos and [merge them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43896/is-it-possible-to-merge-video-files-using-cat) into one:

```
mencoder -ovc copy -oac copy video1.avi video2.avi -o completevideos.avi
```

It might look something like this. Each line of `durations.txt` contains a duration (in milliseconds here), and images are named as in your example. This is meant as an example and may not work as presented:

```
i = 0
while read line; do
    padded = $(printf "%04d\n" $i)
    fps = $(echo "scale=3; 1/$i/1000" | bc -q 2>/dev/null)
    if [ i -eq 0 ]; then
        mencoder "mf://image$padded.jpg" -ovc x264 -mf  fps=$fps -o previous.avi
    else
        mencoder "mf://image$padded.jpg" -ovc x264 -mf  fps=$fps -o next.avi
        mencoder -ovc copy -oac copy previous.avi next.avi -o building.avi
        rm previous.avi
        mv building.avi previous.avi
    fi
    i = $[i + 1];
done < durations.txt
```

The `ffmpeg` tool has [similar](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images) functions:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.png -c:v libx264 -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
ffmpeg -i concat:"intermediate1.mpg|intermediate2.mpg" -c copy intermediate_all.mpg
```